# Datagrid Not Updating after removing row

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Hi there i am using wpf mvvm and my datagrid not updating scource after removing row
can any one help please
here is my viewmodel:

```
public class UserPaymentsVM : ViewModelBase
    {
        private IDataProvider _dataProvider;
        private int _selectedClientID;
        public Clients Client { get; set; }
        private List<Payments> _payments;
        public List<Payments> payments
        {
            get { return _payments; }
            set { _payments = value; RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(payments)); }
        }
```

and here is my view

```
    <Grid Background="Azure">
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=payments, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"

                  AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
                  Height="350" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  SelectedValuePath="pid"
                 SelectedValue="{Binding PayID}">
        </DataGrid>
        <Button  Height="50" Width="100" Content="Remove" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Command="{Binding RemovePayment}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should bound your datagrid to an Observable Collection and implement INotifyCollectionChanged interface so that listeners are notified of dynamic changes, such as when items get removed or the whole list is refreshed.

Comment: I used INotifyCollectionChanged but still not working `public ObservableCollection<Payments> payments
        {
            get { return _payments; }
            set { _payments = value;  /*RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(payments));*/ }
        }`

Comment: public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged `
        {
            add
            {
                ((INotifyCollectionChanged)_payments).CollectionChanged += value;
            }

            remove
            {
                ((INotifyCollectionChanged)_payments).CollectionChanged -= value;
            }
        } `